# Timestamp every echo with hh:mm:ss with leading zero in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, time, cmd, leading-zero

I'm looking to timestamp every `echo` with `hh:mm:ss` in batch. I have been using `%time:~0,-3%` and it worked great until I had to use `set /p`. It omitted the leading space of single digit hours making the line misaligned compared to the rest.

Example:

```
@echo off
echo %time:~0,-3% Hello world!
echo %time:~0,-3% It's a sunny day outside.
set /p "state=%time:~0,-3% How are you? "
echo %time:~0,-3% That's great!
pause >nul
```

Output:

```
 1:59:55 Hello world!
 1:59:55 It's a sunny day outside.
1:59:55 How are you?
 2:00:02 That's great!
```

I could use `set ctime=%time:~0,3%%time:~3,3%%time:~6,2%` and `echo %ctime: =0%` after but that would result in many redundant lines.

Is there a way to combine `%time:~0,-3%` and `%time: =0%`? That would sort me out.

Or maybe force `set /p` not to omit space character? That would work too.

Comment: `set /P` trims leading white-spaces, but you could begin the string with `_` + _backspace_ as a work-around…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a little trickery by capturing a backspace to a variable.

```
@echo off

:: Define BS to contain a backspace
for /f %%a in ('"prompt $H&for %%b in (1) do rem"') do set "BS=%%a"
echo %time:~0,-3% Hello world!
echo %time:~0,-3% It's a sunny day outside.
set /p "state=_%BS%%time:~0,-3% How are you? "
echo %time:~0,-3% That's great!
pause
```

Comment: This is interesting and acceptable! I'd still like to see if someone knows how to combine substring extraction and substring replacement on a single variable.

Comment: @eqagunn, you cannot do sub-string expansion and sub-string substitution in one go, you always have to do one after another; you can do them in one line (using `&`) when you use delayed expansion…

Comment: @aschipfl `set t=%time:~0,-3%&echo !t: =0!` Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For repetitive tasks, a subroutine is a good solution:

```
@echo off
set "stamp=call :stamp"

%stamp% & echo Hello world!
%stamp% & echo It's a sunny day outside.
%stamp% & set /p "state=How are you? "
%stamp% & echo That's great!
pause >nul

:stamp
set "t=%time: =0%"
<nul set /p "=%t:~0,-3%: "
```

Sample output:

```
11:23:15: Hello world!
11:23:15: It's a sunny day outside.
11:23:15: How are you? not that good...
11:23:23: That's great!
```

The advantage is: when there are more tasks to do (here: replace the space with a `0` and cut the milliseconds), it all happens in the subroutine (at one place). Easy to maintain and keeps your main code clean.

Instead of `call :stamp & echo Line to print` you can use a pseudo-macro (`%stamp%`) (like I did), but that's up to you.

Comment: Tried to keep my script out of subroutines, although I could squeeze this one in. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Whilst this doesn't bring any new techniques to the party, *over the suggestions already made*, I've posted it because, I don't really think that there's a need to expect the response on the same line. *(We don't do it in online chat, or messaging apps)*. The idea therefore is to only use `Echo` for the narrative / questions, *(thus having no issues with losing a space)*, and give the end user a new line for their `Set /P` input:

```
@Echo Off
For /F %%G In ('"Prompt $H&For %%H In (1)Do Rem"')Do Set "input=%%G       > "
Echo %TIME:~,-3% Hello world!
Echo %TIME:~,-3% It's a sunny day outside.
Echo %TIME:~,-3% How are you?
Set /P "state=%input%"
Echo %TIME:~,-3% That's great!
Echo %TIME:~,-3% You are %state%.
Pause>NUL
```

Expected output:

```
 9:59:54 Hello world!
 9:59:54 It's a sunny day outside.
 9:59:54 How are you?
       > okay
10:00:01 That's great!
10:00:01 You are okay.
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a timestamp variable like this:

```
set ts=%time: =0%
```

And use that for all timestamps in your file.

That syntax replaces all spaces with 0

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is an old question but I would generate a custom time stamp initially then pass this to a variable so we can re-use as required.

**NOTE:** Out of personal preference I opted to go with a 12 hour time format and hid the seconds (*which can be included again by simply adding `%sec%`). Additionally I also added am/pm*.

Also, if you want to re-add the leading 0 to the hour then all you need to do is remove the following segment of code:

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=0" %%N in ("%hour%") do set "hour=%%N"
```

This was intentionally kept separate to make it easy to remove if not required.

so, (*including Compo's rather great addition*) please see below:

```
mode con: cols=65 lines=20  & color f0

::Get time and format
For /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=:,. " %%A in ('echo %time%') do (
set /a "hour=100%%A%%100"
set min=%%B
set sec=%%C
)

::Add AM/PM to time
if %Hour% geq 12 (
set ampm=pm
set /a "hour-=12"
) else set "ampm=am"
if %hour% equ 0 set "hour=12"
if %hour% lss 10 set "hour=0%hour%"

:: Remove leading 0 from %hour%
for /f "tokens=* delims=0" %%N in ("%hour%") do set "hour=%%N"

::Setup time stamp
set "mytime=%hour%:%min%%ampm% -"

for /F %%G In ('"Prompt $H&For %%H In (1)Do Rem"')Do Set "input=%%G       > "
echo %mytime% Hello world!
echo %mytime% It's a sunny day outside.
echo %mytime% How are you?
set /P "state=%input%"
echo %mytime% That's great!
echo %mytime% You are %state%.

echo. &echo. Press any key to exit. &>nul timeout /t -1 &exit /B
```